# Show that the orthocenter must coincide with one of the vertices of triangle ABC.

Tags: geometry

Given the orthocenter and circumcenter both lie on the nine-point circle prove that the orthocenter must coincide with one of the vertices of $\triangle ABC$.

I have already proved that the orthocenter and circumcenter both lie on the nine-point circle by introducing some simple circular logic and its obvious that $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle even though I haven't proved that, but how do I specifically prove that the orthocenter must coincide with one of the vertices of $\triangle ABC$ in order for both the orthocenter and the circumcenter to be on the nine-point circle? Please Help.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot: If you must continue cluttering the Active Questions queue with trivial TeX edits to ancient questions, please note that the proper TeX for "$\triangle$" is `$\triangle$`, not `$\Delta$`. (We don't want someone dredging these questions back up *again* just to even-more-trivially re-edit your edits.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot: I hope you realize that what I'm really suggesting is: *Please stop making trivial edits to ancient questions.*

Answer (score 1):

Since the legs in a right triangle are altitudes as well, and the orthocenter is the point where altitudes intersect, you can conclude that the orthocenter has to be the corner with the right angle. So if you have proven that $ABC$ is a right triangle, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D, E, F$ be the foot of the perpendiculars from $A, B, C$ respectively.
Let $H$ be the orthocenter of the circle. We know that $H$ lies on $AD, BE, CF$.
Let $A_M, B_M, C_M$ be the midpoints of $AH, BH, CH$ respectively.

If the orthocenter lies on the nine-point circle, then $H$ must be either $A_M$ or $D$.
If $H=A_M$, then $H= A_M = A$, and so we are done.
If $H=D$, then this implies that $BC$ is perpendicular to $AC$, and $BC$ is perpendicular to $AB$. As Ivan points out, this is only possible if $D=B$ or $D=C$, in which we get that $H$ is one of the vertices.

Comment: $H=D=B$ and $H=D=C$ are both possible. Your argument that $BC$ is perpendicular to both $AC$ and $AB$ only works when $H=D$ is neither $B$ nor $C$. Fortunately for those two cases, we are done anyway.

Comment: @IvanLoh Ah yes, thanks!